# Java Graphics 2D render quality issue

Tags: java, render, graphics2d

Using Java Graphics 2D to render image minute by minute to create time lapse video cause blurry image when running. Image resolution on Full HD (1920 X 1080) *Blurry appears on image not on video.*

I use buffered image as the configuration as bellow

```
BufferedImage alt = config.createCompatibleImage(resX, resY);        
Graphics2D g2 = alt.createGraphics();
```

When `resX` and `resY` are

```
final int resX = 1920;
final int resY = 1080;
```

Trying to draw circle and text with this x,y configuration

```
// Image
g2.drawImage(img, leftSideX, resYTop + paddingImg, resX - leftSideX - paddingImg, resY - resYTop - paddingImg - paddingImg, null);

// Draw Cirlce 1
g2.setColor(new Color(0,161,155));
g2.fillArc(78, 160, 200, 200, 90, -340);

g2.setColor(new Color(73, 73, 73));
g2.fillArc(98, 180, 160, 160, 90, -340);

// Percentage
g2.setColor(new Color(0,161,155));
g2.setFont(g2.getFont().deriveFont(45F)); 
g2.drawString("10%", 135, 275 );  

// Draw circle Legend
g2.setColor(new Color(0,161,155));
g2.fillArc(paddingLegend, resY - 150, paddingLegend, paddingLegend, 360, 360);

g2.setColor(new Color(249,178,52));
g2.fillArc(paddingLegend, resY - 120, paddingLegend, paddingLegend, 360, 360);

g2.setColor(new Color(190,22,35));
g2.fillArc(paddingLegend, resY - 90, paddingLegend, paddingLegend, 360, 360);

g2.setColor(new Color(178,178,178));
g2.setFont(g2.getFont().deriveFont( 15F ));
g2.drawString("Occupied / Moving Goods", paddingLegend + 30, resY - 135 );                 
g2.drawString("Goods idle > 2 days and < 5 days", paddingLegend + 30, resY - 105); 
g2.drawString("Goods idle \u2265 5 days", paddingLegend + 30, resY - 75 );          

// Capacity Level Title
g2.setFont(g2.getFont().deriveFont( 20F ));
g2.drawString("Capacity Level ", paddingLeftSubTitle + paddingLegend, resYTop + paddingTopSubTitle1 + paddingLegend); 

// Goods Movement Title
g2.setFont(g2.getFont().deriveFont( 20F ));
g2.drawString("Goods Movement ", paddingLeftSubTitle + paddingLegend, resYTop + paddingTopSubTitle2 + paddingLegend);
```

and here are the result
[image: image 1]

Blur appears on circle and text
[image: problem 1]

[image: problem 2]

[image: problem 3]

as you can see from the image above the circle and text are totally blurry but the warehouse image are not blur at all. I have tried bellow code and nothing improvement.

```
g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_RENDERING, RenderingHints.VALUE_RENDER_QUALITY);
g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_STROKE_CONTROL, RenderingHints.VALUE_STROKE_PURE);
```

**How I can improve my image render quality?**

Many Thanks

Comment: Things to consider. Scaling - some scaling will cause antialiasing issues. I'd also look at the available [text rending hints](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/text/renderinghints.html) as well and see if they help. It's also difficult to know, but the images appear to affected by JPEG compression artefacts, but that could just be the captures themselves

Comment: I had tried text rendering hint on https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/RenderingHints.html nothing works for me. How I can use scaling but I have already set x,y for image resolution 1920 X 1080?

Comment: The question is, are you scaling the images?  Since all we have are some out of context code and screen grabs, it's some what difficult to know where the issue might be

Comment: No scaling. I just draw on x,y coordinate

Comment: Well, I'm out of guesses, consider providing a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your issue

Comment: @MadProgrammer Question edited. With minimal code and provide all parts needed to reproduce the problem

Comment: Since the out-of-context code snippet won't compile, it's not a [minimal or complete example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

So, when I patch your code together and run it, I get...

[image: Nice]

which seems fine to me.  So either it's something else going on in your code which we're not privy to, or it's a hardware/driver issue.

Consider providing a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) - this removes the guess work and provides us with a better oppurunity to understand the problem and provide possible solutions

Nb: I'm rending the output at 1920x1080, I've just clipped the output for the post

ps- I know this is not a "answer", but I'm not getting any help from the OP

## `CircularProgress`

Because I haven't done it a hundred times before...

[image: CircularProgress]

While you can do this kind of thing use the regular 2D Graphics API, I tend to find the "shapes" API a much more useful approach, especially for generating complex re-usable shapes

```
import java.awt.BasicStroke;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.geom.AffineTransform;
import java.awt.geom.Arc2D;
import java.awt.geom.Area;
import java.awt.geom.Ellipse2D;
import java.awt.geom.Path2D;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.Timer;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class CircleProgressTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new CircleProgressTest();
    }

    public CircleProgressTest() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        private double progress = 0d;
        private double radius = 90;
        private CircleProgress cp;

        public TestPane() {
            cp = new CircleProgress(radius, 20, 0d);
            Timer timer = new Timer(50, new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    if (progress >= 1.0) {
                        ((Timer)(e.getSource())).stop();
                        progress = 1.0;
                    } else {
                        progress += 0.001;
                    }
                    cp = new CircleProgress(radius, 20, progress);
                    repaint();
                }
            });
            timer.start();
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(200, 200);
        }

        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
            g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
            g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_RENDERING, RenderingHints.VALUE_RENDER_QUALITY);
            g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_STROKE_CONTROL, RenderingHints.VALUE_STROKE_PURE);

            double x = (getWidth() - (radius * 2d)) / 2d;
            double y = (getHeight() - (radius * 2d)) / 2d;

            g2d.transform(AffineTransform.getTranslateInstance(x, y));

            g2d.setStroke(new BasicStroke(4f, BasicStroke.CAP_ROUND, BasicStroke.JOIN_ROUND));
            g2d.setColor(Color.DARK_GRAY);
            g2d.draw(cp);
            g2d.setColor(new Color(0,161,155));
            g2d.fill(cp);

            g2d.dispose();
        }

    }

    public class CircleProgress extends Path2D.Double {

        private double radius;
        private double thickness; // subtracted from radius
        private double progress;

        public CircleProgress(double radius, double thickness, double progress) {
            this.radius = radius;
            this.thickness = thickness;
            this.progress = progress;

            build();
        }

        protected void build() {
            double innerRadius = radius - thickness;
            if (progress >= 1.0) {
                Area outter = new Area(new Ellipse2D.Double(0, 0, radius * 2d, radius * 2d));
                Area inner = new Area(new Ellipse2D.Double(thickness, thickness, innerRadius * 2d, innerRadius * 2d));
                outter.subtract(inner);
                append(outter, true);
            } else if (progress <= 0.0) {
                // What does this actually mean...?
            } else {
                double extent = -(360.0 * progress);
                double startAt = 90d;

                append(new Arc2D.Double(0, 0, radius * 2d, radius * 2d, startAt, extent, Arc2D.OPEN), true);
                append(new Arc2D.Double(thickness, thickness, innerRadius * 2d, innerRadius * 2d, startAt + extent, -extent, Arc2D.OPEN), true);
                closePath();
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: The problem seems are on `ImageIO.write(alt, "jpg", f);` I use ImageIO to write bufferimage on file. Any idea?

Comment: Well, don't use `jpg` to start with, it's a loosely compression, use PNG, which is lossless